# disable xampp redirect http to https

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https, xampp

I created VirtualHost at my xampp in localhost for wordpress and add this code in httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mysitefolder
DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/mysitefolder"
ServerName mysitefolder
ErrorLog "logs/mysitefolder-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/mysitefolder-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

but when enter http://mysitefolder in browser it's aout redirect to https://mysitefolder and not load my site. how can disable https and only using http ?thank you

Comment: nothing in that code redirects

Comment: show your `htacess` and check in `config` table for base url

Answer (score 42):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but if you are using Chrome and a `.dev`  local server domain, have a look at [this post](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/). Chrome have purchased the `.dev` gTLD and now force the redirect to `https://`. If so, consider using `.test` or some other domain. A quick way to test it would be to try another browser.

Comment: Today i got the same reaction on my localhost domain which is `.dev` nice point dude!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was looking for hours for an answer to it.

Comment: Notice: Firefox does now also show this behavior. See the linked post above.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. For me, it was a problem with my `.htaccess` file. I had to remove the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After that, I emptied the cache and did a hard reload. Fixed the issue.

You may also need to clear cookies, local/session storage, etc. depending on your specific needs.

Answer (score -1):

In your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yourwordpressurl.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourwordpressurl.com');
```

This will force your site to use http:// instead of https

Answer (score -1):

**Answer: Use Microsoft Edge**

As an addition to Geoff's v useful post: Use Edge instead. My domains work fine there.

Why Google needed to do this tweak to Chrome is beyond me. Surely (normally) any web address is first checked against local DNS before going external or am I daft.

Anyhow Edge works but will probably make them .loc or something (I assume .loc is still OK) and return to Chrome. I will find it very funny if I end up liking Edge and ditching Chrome. If only wishing made it so.

I hate monopolistic behaviours like this. It used to be Microsoft now Google and Amazon worst offenders. Apple is a closed garden ... and I hate that too.

I am getting old :-(

Comment: Thanks for this anser, it works even in 2020. The other anser from @Geoff did also not really "ansewer" the question, so the actual problem would not be solved but just be worked around. The funny thing is that your answer even worked after MS changed Edge to be Chromium. Cheers Mate!