# localhost redirect to https and loops the url

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost

Hi im configuring a project in my localhost, but im getting this problem, when i try to enter this url  `localhost/project/public/` it redirects to HTTPS, and the other problem is that it repeats the url this way `https://localhost/project/public/project/public`.

This is my .htaccess file

> Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore the Moodle Folder for the Laravel's Route System
RewriteCond $1 !^(cefovi)

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Im not sure if this file is the problem or i have something else misconfigured. I have another project that supposedly has the same structure.

This project has inside the public folder an index file that calls the laravel project and a moodle folder called cefovi

Im not very sure whats the problem, hope you can help, thx

Im using Xampp and this is my httpd-vhosts file

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you also include your `VirtualHost` configuration? I think HTTPS redirect is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the redirect to HTTPS is probably because of your virtual host configuration. Please check find a statemnt

SSLEngine on

in your Virtualhost configuration and change it to

SSLEngine off

in addition, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725774/disable-xampp-redirect-http-to-https) similar question.

The URL repeat is likely because of the relative url used on href's If you are on laravel template, please use links like this.

```
<a href="{{url('/posts')}}">link</a>
```

instead of using

```
<a href="/posts">link</a>
```

In addition, what you write on the  tag affects how your references/url's are addressed. i.e. if you have `<base href="/project/public">` in your template, all the other relative references will have the "/project/public" prepend.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Im not sure if thisis the file you´re asking