# How to correctly remove / uninstall a cert from Windows machine? Only .dev domain is having problems

Tags: windows, xampp, ssl-certificate

I did followed this [site](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/) to created an unvalidated cert. Now what happened here is that cert is issued to "elliot.dev" and I tried to go to "mmc.exe" and "Disabled all purposed for this cert", and restarted my machine but it is still not work.

When I install that cert, I imported into

Local Machine >> Trusted Root Certification Authorities

and it caused my customized XAMPP local domain "elliot.dev" not working and no longer accessible to http://elliot.dev . Browser redirected me to https://elliot.dev and it is inaccessible as well because of untrust cert SSL error.

How should I completely remove it? Thanks.

---

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of searching, found that this is because of the `.dev` domain is force redirected to https by default for most browser Chrome and Firefox. It is legit .dev gTLD and preloaded HSTS for most browsers.

Source:
https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726962/5802100

Answer (score 0):

To remove a installed certificate, open `MMC.exe` and find your imported certificate(should be in `Certificates/Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates`), right click on it, and select `Delete`.

You are redirected to https://* because you enabled it in your virtual host configurations:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
     SSLEngine on    # <--- This line.
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/site.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/site.test/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: but it work for all other name "elliot.io" for example, it just don't work for "elliot.dev" , both names I've already specified in hosts file